# Add a function to a button made with userscript

Tags: javascript, function, button, userscripts

I know how to create a button with userscript, but I don't know how to attach a function to the button with userscript. How do I attach a function to the button with userscript? I would also like to add an "id" to the button with userscript. How do I do that? Thanks.

```
var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");        // Create a <button> element
var text = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");       // Create a text node
button.appendChild(text);                                // Append the text to <button>
document.body.appendChild(button);

function clickMe() {
alert("Hi");
} //end of function clickMe()
```

Comment: [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score -2):

To attach a function to the button with userscript

```
button.addEventListener("click", clickMe, false);
```